# Autorenewable subscription in-app purchases in iphone?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an iPhone application in which I am using Auto renewable subscriptions using MKstorekit4.1.I am successfully implemented it and I'm getting the server responses.Actually I want to use this subscription active for 1 month. I am giving value in the config.plist as 30.But when I'm testing I need to purchase again in the same day? I need that purchase to be active for 30 days. MKstorekit says they have already taken care of it with the following code.Then why I have this scenario.

```
-(BOOL) isSubscriptionActive
{    
if([[self.verifiedReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"receipt"] objectForKey:@"expires_date"]){

    NSLog(@"%@",self.verifiedReceiptDictionary);
    NSTimeInterval expiresDate = [[[self.verifiedReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"receipt"] objectForKey:@"expires_date"] doubleValue]/1000.0;
    NSLog(@"%f",expiresDate);
     NSLog(@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    return expiresDate > [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

}else{

    NSString *purchasedDateString = [[self.verifiedReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"receipt"] objectForKey:@"purchase_date"];        
    if(!purchasedDateString) {
        NSLog(@"Receipt Dictionary from Apple Server is invalid: %@", verifiedReceiptDictionary);
        return NO;
    }
      NSLog(@"%@",purchasedDateString);
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //2011-07-03 05:31:55 Etc/GMT
    purchasedDateString = [purchasedDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" Etc/GMT" withString:@""];    
    NSLocale *POSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [df setLocale:POSIXLocale];        
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];            
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *purchasedDate = [df dateFromString: purchasedDateString];        
    int numberOfDays = [purchasedDate timeIntervalSinceNow] / (-86400.0);
        NSLog(@"%@",purchasedDate);
         NSLog(@"%@",numberOfDays);
    return (self.subscriptionDays > numberOfDays);        
   }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the sandbox,one month subscription expires every 5 minutes,and after 30 minutes since first purchase it stops auto renewing,so don't get frustrated,when you notice that it doesn't auto renew anymore,or expired before you expected that.

Comment: for 1 month subscription we need to give the value as 30 in config plist.is that right?

Comment: i have also one more doubt that the above snipet is enough for checking the auto renewal?or we want to customise it.

Comment: I mean, if you publish your app, yeah,you have to give value of 30 days.In my own app, i don't use MSKit,i just save the expire date that apple gives me from receipt in USerDefaults,and every launch check,if [NSDate date] is bigger than that.If so,i validate the latets receipt i saved and it tells me,if user had prolounged the subscription.

Comment: can u look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040276/aws-iossdk-for-s3-integration-in-iphone

Comment: Really,i don't know the answer,but i think,that NSStream is what you need

Comment: [MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:kFeatureAId]) is not working with ios 4.3 ?Do u know why as you r a master of subscription? But in ios 5 simulator it is working fine.

Comment: Oh man sorry ..it was not working in device.either it is ios 5 or 4.3.But i will be successfully recieving the response from itunes server.is that due to the server change of simulator and device

Comment: Maybe it's really not active,is that possible?What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: i mean all functionalities that i added according to purchase is not working.but it working fine in ios5 simulator
 if([[MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:kFeatureAId]) { //unlock[self.view addSubview:joinn.view]}
here if the subscription exists i am adding some other view. and if not some another view.fine in simulator.but in device showing only the unsubscribed view.

Comment: I am very much frustrated can u help me

Comment: It really means,that you are not subscribed)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9786/discussion-between-nikita-pestrov-and-bugfinder)

Comment: i didnt get u i am getting the response from server with a status  status = 21006;

Comment: This means,that subsrcription is out of date.Come to chat)

Comment: but how it will be happening in simulator

Comment: and also when i again try to by it will show u have already subscribed to this

Comment: when i got the status 0 the desired result is not happening.i was done just nothing but [MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:kFeatureAId]){

Comment: then inside that i was adding a view.suprisingly it was working fine in the ios5 simulator

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].